# Proper way to create an HTML5 input element that is "required"

Tags: javascript, html

What is the proper way to create an HTML5 input element with the "required" attribute?

for example, in the HTML, I would use something like:

```
<input id="myId" name="myName" type="text" required>
```

But I need to do this in JavaScript using:

```
var inputElement = document.createElement("input");
    inputElement.id = "myId";
    inputElement.name = "myName";
    inputElement.type = "text";
```

Once I create this element, how do I add the "required" attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just set it like the others, you can use true or basically any string.

```
inputElement.required = true;
```

or

```
inputElement.required = "required";
```

Comment: Don't use strings if you're setting the property rather than the attribute.  `required` is a boolean property, and "required" only works because strings other than `""` are truthy.